# The function $y=f(x)$ has the property that the chord joining any two points $A(x_1,f(x_1)),B(x_2,f(x_2))$ always intersect $y-$axis at $(0,2x_1x_2)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions

The function $y=f(x)$ has the property that the chord joining any two points $A(x_1,f(x_1)),B(x_2,f(x_2))$ always intersect $y-$axis at $(0,2x_1x_2)$.Given that $f(1)=-1$.
Find $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx$ and find the largest interval in which $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

---

I tried to find the $f(x)$ from the given information but no success.
The equation of chord is given by $$\frac{f(x)-f(x_1)}{x-x_1}=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$
It passes through $(0,2x_1x_2)$
$$\frac{2x_1x_2-f(x_1)}{-x_1}=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$
After cross multiplying and simplification,we get
$$2x_1x_2(x_2-x_1)=x_2f(x_1)-x_1f(x_2)$$
After this I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the chord through $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ is

$$y-f(x_1)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1).$$ Since $(0,2x_1x_2)$ is a point of this line we have

$$2x_1x_2-f(x_1)=-\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}x_1.$$ Now, we consider $(x_1,f(x_1))=(1,-1),$ (because we know that $f(1)=-1$) to get

$$2x_2+1=-\frac{f(x_2)+1}{x_2-1}.$$

Thus you can get $f(x)$ explicitly.